# Explain that for $m<-6$ the equation $x^4+mx^2-m-6=0$ will always have 4 solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As in the title, explain that for $m<-6$ the equation $x^4+mx^2-m-6=0$ will always have 4 solutions.

For $m<-6$ the expression $-m-6$ in the equation will always be positive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With almost no calculation:*

Setting $t=x^2$, this is equivalent to saying the quadratic equation
$$t^2+mt-m-6=0$$
has two positive solutions if $m>-6$.

Indeed it has two real solutions, whatever the value of $m$, since the discriminant is
$$\Delta=m^2+4m+24=(m+2)^2+20\ge 20.$$

Now the product of these roots is $-m-6>0\iff m<-6$. In such a case, both roots have the same sign.

This common sign is also the sign of their sum, which is $-m$. Hence they're positive.

Comment: Why is it equivalent to say that ...? ("This is equivalent to saying...") How do you derive $m^2+4m+24...$?

Comment: It is the standard change of variable $t=x^2$  for biquadratic equations, as seen in high school. For the discriminant, I apply the formula, then complete the square.

Comment: You should mention then that $t=x^2$ and substitution $t$ in ... gives ....  Also you should show how you how you derive the discriminant from the equation. Otherwise your answer is unclear.

Comment: $D=b^2-4ac$ gives $D=(mt)^2-4t^2*(-m-6)$? How you do derive $m^2+4m+24$?

Comment: OK, I mentioned the substitution. For the discriminant, I don't agree. I don't give a full correction. People asking questions are supposed to have studied the subject, and computing a discriminant is part of the basics on quadratic equations.

Comment: @Joe: No, the discriminant is computed with the *coefficients*, not the unknown.

Comment: I agree, however different doctrines around the world use different notation. If you don't mention the keywords like discriminant then your answer is clearly biased, based on the fact that everyone went through the same high school as you did.

Comment: Right, I added the keyword. Actually, I thought I had written it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now the product of **these roots** is..."?

Comment: The product od the two real solutions to the equation. I use Vieta's relations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a biquadratic equation, use quadratic completion to get
$$
(x^2+m/2)^2=(m/2+1)^2+5
$$
This should only have positive solutions for $x^2$, which is only the case when $m<0$ and
$$
(m/2)^2>(m/2+1)^2+5
$$

Comment: What is $(x^2+m/2)^2$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $x^4+mx^2+m^2/4$, whatever else would it be?

Comment: What is it supposed to mean? How does it relate to the equation in the question?

Comment: It is the completed square that absorbs all of the terms with $x$. -- Do a recap on quadratic equations, my answer is just an analysis of the solution formula.